# Synchronize two folders over sftp?

Tags: linux, macos, sync, rsync, osx-yosemite

I have a cloned git repository in a directory and a sftp server, I want the server to be in sync with my repository.

I've been trying multiple Atom/Sublime Text plugins with no luck, they only upload files after I save them, which means if I checkout to different branch I see no difference on the server (I have to open every changed file separately and then save them...).

I know what I want to achieve is totally doable with rsync, although I don't really know how. I have an address, port, username, password, but I can't really sync two directories, how do I do that?

When I try:

```
rsync -avzh Users/me/Desktop/project username@server.com :/path/on/server
```

The connection gets refused, also I don't know where to provide password to my account.

I know there's plenty of software that does it automagically but I:

- want something freeware
- can't do any changes on the server

So in short - how do I sync two folders, one on OSX another one somewhere online on Yosemite? I'm not a power user although I know how to use terminal.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you ssh to the server?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's vps-classic by ovh, see: https://www.ovh.co.uk/vps/vps-classic.xml - if ssh is imporant here I can always ask the owner of the account (my boss)..

Comment: `rsync` is generally used over ssh in this type of scenario, so if you can get the ssh details - which your boss would definitely have been given (or he can create an account for you) then you'll be able to get this working

Comment: Can you tell me how rsync for that directory would look like? What if I can't use ssh, I've checked ssh-ing to this server and seems like I can't do that.

Comment: What access *do* you have to the server?

Comment: *The connection gets refused, also I don't know where to provide password to my account*. You must have passwordless access (*i.e.*, using cryptographic keys) for this to work.

Comment: I don't have an SSH access after all. Can I do anything to sync these two folders? sftp access only. cc @Paul & MariusMatuatiae, thanks!

Comment: @Wordpressor sftp is over ssh.  Do you mean ftps?  Can you explain exactly what methods you have to access the server and what you have used to ensure they work?

Comment: @Paul, I have only 4 things: login, password, host & path. I've accessed the server using Cyberduck, also I tried to sync two folders using Sublime SFTP plugin for Sublime Text and many SFTP plugins for Atom, but it's not perfect and uploads files to server only on save (so if I for example checkout to different branch in git nothing gets uploaded unless I open every changed file separately).